# PHP - Getting content after last but one comma

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get addresses split into address + city state.

For example:

```
some street name, Seattle, WA
other stree, number, something, Seattle, WA
```

Assuming the last two items of the address will always be city, state... how can I split all that is before the last second comma?

So, I want to get an array or so with:

```
array[0] = some street name
array[1] = Seattle, WA

array[0] = other stree, number, something
array[1] = Seattle, WA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`explode`, `array_slice` and `implode` can help you here:

```
function address($input) {
    $parts = explode(",", $input);
    $address = array_slice($parts, 0, count($parts) - 2);
    $city_state = array_slice($parts, count($parts) - 2);
    return array(trim(implode(",", $address)), trim(implode(",", $city_state)));
}

address("some street name, Seattle, WA");
// =>
Array
(
    [0] => some street name
    [1] => Seattle, WA
)

address("other street, number, something, Seattle, WA");
// =>
Array
(
    [0] => other street, number, something
    [1] => Seattle, WA
)
```

Answer (score 1):

explode() would work, but keep the following in mind: Your city / state has a comma in it, and will not go in the second array if you split with a comma.
Here's an example of how the code would work.

```
$str = "Some Street Name, Seattle, WA"
$array = explode(",", $str);
```

Your array would look something like this.

```
array[0] = Some Street Name
array[1] = Seattle
array[2] = WA
```

The only issue is that when you split the string into these parts, WA is put into the third index (array[2]). You can easily combine this element later.

```
$array[1] .= ", " . $array[2];
$array[2] = null;
```

You are then left with

```
array[0] = Some Street Name
array[1] = Seattle, WA
```

Edit: If you're dealing with multiple commas, I recommend you take a different approach to your code. I assume you're doing an order form, no? If so, prompt users with a form to fill out information. With radio buttons, check boxes, drop downs, and others, your data will be much easier to handle.

There's no real way of PHP to determine what is a street address and whatnot, and no real way of determining how many commas there will be.

Comment: You could use the `count()` function on the array, and get element associated with the `highest count` and then `count minus one` to get the second to last one, which in total would be the last two, which would always be `Seattle (count()-1)` and `WA (count())`

Comment: After that, you could use `strlen()` on the last two arrays `(Seattle, WA)` which would give you `11` back and then use the `substr()` function like `substr("other stree, number, something, Seattle, WA",0,-13)` which would return just `other stree, number, something`, and you would still have `Seattle, WA` from before

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression, you could break the input up into sections, with this in mind: the end of every string will be something along the lines of `[^,]+, [^,]+`. Keeping that in consideration, [you could formulate a regex such as this](http://regexr.com?36ur3):

```
^(.*), ([^,]+,[^,]+)$
```

This will separate the string into **the beginning** `(.*)`, **the separator** `,`, and **the city and state** `([^,]+,[^,]+)`. This will give you two capture groups, and will work successfully for any strings such that they're not *just* the city and state (ex: `Seattle, WA`).

Answer (score 0):

use explode and you get these result of first string

```
$array[0] = some street name
$array[1] = Seattle
$array[2] = WA

$cityIndex = count($array)-2;
$stateIndex = count($array)-1;
```

now you can use them

```
$array[$cityIndex].=','.$array[$stateIndex];
```

finally you got

```
$array[0] = some street name
$array[1] = Seattle, WA
```

Answer (score 0):

array_slice() will let you pop however many elements off the end of the array you want, irrespective of the overall number.

```
$address =  'some street name, Seattle, WA';
$city_state =   array_slice(explode(',', $address), -2, 2);
print_r($city_state);
```

Outputs: Array ( [0] => Seattle [1] => WA )